# Hold event with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, web

I really would like to know if there is any way to execute a function when you tap (on mobile device) or click (on desktop device) a form submit/anchor/etc. and hold it for some amount of time WITHOUT using jQuery!

```
function clicked() {
    //set some kind of timer or so...
}

function toBeExecutedNMillisecondsAfterAnchorWasClicked() {
     //do some stuff...
}
```

Comment: using `setTimeout(function(){...}, intervalInMilliseconds)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
(function() {

  var mouseTimer;
  function mouseDown() { 
      mouseUp();
      mouseTimer = window.setTimeout(execMouseDown,2000); //set timeout to fire in 2 seconds when the user presses mouse button down
  }

  function mouseUp() { 
      if (mouseTimer) window.clearTimeout(mouseTimer);  //cancel timer when mouse button is released
      div.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
  }

  function execMouseDown() { 
      div.style.backgroundColor = "#CFCF00";
  }

  var div = document.getElementById("bam");
  div.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);
  document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp);  //listen for mouse up event on body, not just the element you originally clicked on
  
}());
```

```css
#bam { width:100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<div id="bam"> Hold mouse button for 2 seconds. </div>
<p>Bacon</p>
<p>Bacon</p>
<p>Bacon</p>
<p>Bacon</p>
<p>Bacon</p>
<p>Bacon</p>
<p>Bacon</p>
<p>Bacon</p>
<p>Bacon</p>
```

Comment: great code but a little explanation would have helped to understand. Just the comments alone are not enough.

Comment: The code is simple. What do you not understand? Seems pretty straight forward hence why I left it to minimal comments. Add a mousedown event to the element which triggers a timer to execute. Add mouseup event to the document. If the up event is triggered cancel the timer that was added. If mouse is not released in the set peroid of time, the timer executes.

Comment: It don't work in mobiles.

Comment: @JohanDonadoB. so use touch events on mobile

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this to get the difference between mousedown and mouseup. Then, I would do an if/else statement with that diff variable that I created.

Here's a fiddle:: http://jsfiddle.net/mgfkdu9x/2/

```
<button id="element">My Button</button>

(function () {
    var element = document.getElementById('element'),
        start, 
        end;

    element.onmousedown = function () {
      setTimeout(function() { 
          if (element.onmousedown=true)
              toBeExecutedNMillisecondsAfterAnchorWasClicked();
      }, 5000);
    };

})();

function toBeExecutedNMillisecondsAfterAnchorWasClicked() {
     console.log('function start');
}
```

Comment: why `+new Date();`, but not `Date.now()`?

Comment: They're the same, but I'll update it because Date.now() does look prettier :)

Comment: this code wont work as i want it to because it only checks the time when you release the button. If you hold it and 5 seconds pass nothing will happen until you release the button.

Comment: oh gotcha - Updated my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function:

```
function clicked() {
  // Execute your function after 2000 milliseconds
  setTimeout(toBeExecutedNMillisecondsAfterAnchorWasClicked, 2000);
}
```

Comment: This is not the question, which was about detecting the length of a press.

Comment: @torazaburo, I don't think it was about the length of the key press .. Maybe question needs to be clearer

Comment: Question said "tap... **and hold it for some amount of time**".

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/mgfkdu9x/4/

```
(function() {

  var mouseTimer;
  function mouseDown() { 
      mouseUp();
      mouseTimer = window.setTimeout(execMouseDown,500);
  }

  function mouseUp() { 
      if (mouseTimer) window.clearTimeout(mouseTimer);
      div.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
      setTimeout(function(){
          a.setAttribute("href", "google.com");
      },0);
  }

  function execMouseDown() { 
      div.style.backgroundColor = "#CFCF00";
      a.setAttribute("href", "javascript:void();");
  }

  var div = document.getElementById("div");
  var a = document.getElementById("anchor");
  div.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);
  document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp);

}());
```

edited espacarellos code so it works for anchors with href too.

Answer (score -3):

If you don't want to make the default behaviour, you should prevent it and then execute your function after the time you wish to pass.

To keep it simple I would do:

```
document.getElementById("yourElementId").addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function(){
        //YOUR CODE GOES HERE
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: taht code would execute the function in the timeout even if you released the button before the two secs.

Comment: Excuse me but i don't know by you vote my down. You didn't specify that.

Comment: i did not vote down... i cant even vote... not enough reputation