# How can I simulate pointerdown Event in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a div that has pointerdown event listener and I would like to simulate pointer down event by script.
How do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hold event with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402897/hold-event-with-javascript)

Comment: NO this is mouse down event. I'd like to simulate pointer down;

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2705583/104380

Answer (score 3):

#### [MDN spec for creating & triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events):

```js
// create a specific "pointerdown" event
var myEvent = new PointerEvent('pointerdown')

// Listen for the event (POC)
document.body.addEventListener('pointerdown', console.log);

// Dispatch the event (on the "<body>" element)
document.body.dispatchEvent(myEvent );
```

As you can see I am using the [`PointerEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent/PointerEvent) constructor.

Different *events* have different constructors, and you need to look which one has a constructor, and if there's none, you should use `CustomEvent` constructor.

---

Probably 99% of any DOM-related questions are already answered on MDN docs, you only need to connected the pieces together.

Comment: your solution is available when I want to create new event but I'd like to dispatch existing Event so I can't get that event and dispatch it. the div has  pointerdown event listener and I want to click on an image to simulate pointerDown event for that div.

Comment: @Shayan - You first must *create* an event in order to *dispatch* it. There is no "existing" event. What is stopping you from using my answer? In what **exact** way does it not help?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
const el = document.querySelector('#my-element');

el.addEventListener('pointerdown', (event) => {
  console.log('Pointer down event');
});

const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  el.dispatchEvent(new PointerEvent("pointerdown"));
});
```

```html
<div id="my-element">Hello world</div>
<button type="button">Simulate event</button>
```

For reference, [MDN has documentation on simulating events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).