# How to add a (clicked_id) to a such function with various time depended events? Why this.id doesn't work in this case?

Tags: javascript, html

The below code appears often and is always missing a `clicked_id`, but why? It is always defined `var button = document.getElementById("button");` but not as `var button = document.getElementById(clicked_id);` with `<button id="button" onclick="time(this.id);">`?

**How to make this code possible to run for both `button1` and `button2`?**

The below is working but not in a way I want it to run. I am not pasting a broken code because I don't have an answer yet. I don't have problems with creating an `onclick` event but I can't modify a function below to make it work.  In code no 2, the id is not specified but taken from the `clicked_id` of an already exsiting span. In code no 1 I cant make it work with `clicked_id`. I tried several ideas.

The similar posts are here but they all are missing changeable `clicked_id`:

1 https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113587/detect-how-long-an-html-button-is-pressed
2 [Hold event with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402897/hold-event-with-javascript/27403277#27403277)

```
<button id="button">click</button>
<button id="button2">click</button>
<script>
(function(window, document, undefined){
    'use strict';
    var start;
    var end;
    var delta;
    var button = document.getElementById("button");

    button.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
        start = new Date();
    });

    button.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
        end = new Date();
        delta = end - start;
        if (delta > 0 && delta < 500) {
            alert("less than half second:");
        }
        if (delta > 1000) {
            alert("more than a second:");
        }
    });
})(window, document);
</script>
```

code number 2 which I want to merge with code 1.

````
<span id="button1" onclick="newfunction(this.id);"> text of button 1</span>
<span id="button2" onclick="newfunction(this.id);"> text of button 2</span>
<script>
function newfunction (clicked_id){
var era = (clicked_id);
var x = document.getElementById(era).innerText;
alert(x);
}
</script>
```
````

Comment: I have no idea what `clicked_id` you are referring to. It's not a thing that exists, maybe it's your own variable's name...? You are adding a listener to a button so that it can be called when it's clicked - it's not logical to talk about the ID of something clicked when it's not even clicked yet... And you know which button you want to listen on, so that's where you add your listener. And if you want it on multiple buttons, just add the same listener to all of them, or give them a unique class and use `document.querySelectorAll` and loop over its results, adding the listener to each...

Comment: I wrote the second code to show what I want to achieve in code no 1. In code no 2,  the id is not specified but taken from the clicked_id of an already exsiting span. In code no 1 I cant make it work with clicked_id.

Comment: Alright I will try with document.querySelectorAll, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always have an eventlistener on the parent element (like `div#test` in my example), and then check if is is the right element that was clicked (like `e.targt.nodeName == 'BUTTON'`). In the example I add the starttime as a property to the element, so if you have more buttons (or that ever) you always know that is is the right starttime. And then you not have global values that you need to keep track of.

I'm not sure that the button element is the right choice in your case. This could also be solved with any other element.

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  if (e.target.nodeName == 'BUTTON') {
    e.target.starttime = Date.now();
  }
});

document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
  if (e.target.nodeName == 'BUTTON') {
    let endtime = Date.now();
    let delta = endtime - parseInt(e.target.starttime);
    console.log(delta);
    if (delta > 0 && delta < 500) {
    alert("less than half second:");
    }
    if (delta > 1000) {
    alert("more than a second:");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <button id="button1">click 1</button>
  <button id="button2">click 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, you solved it. I was all the time trying to make this clicked_id works but your solutions goes around and is perfect. I think I will figure out from here how to make it being active depending on the passed time for various events. My upvote can't  be visible yet because I don't have enough points.

Comment: Why do you say that BUTTON is not a good choice - seems reasonable to me!